# FB, Twitter and Stumbleupon count for whole domain name

Tags: facebook, api, twitter

On one of our websites http://fervr.net (bottom right corner) we have a count of how many Facebook likes, Twitter and Stumbles (Stumbleupon). 
The problem; it only reflects the count of likes, twitter and stumbles on the homepage url and not how many shares we have through out the website (whole domain name fervr.net).

Any smart heads out there who have experienced the same and found the API for the count of all  shared likes, tweets and stumbles through out the domain name?

Thanks and regards

Comment: For facebook, each url is considered a separate object.  So you will have to query the graph api for each url separately and total up the likes on your side.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, for Facebook unfortunately that is what you will have to do. As for Twitter, if you are looking for the amount of times that the URL/Post was tweeted then you would have to query for each and total them in your app.